# Overriding Accepted Answers

Tags: feature-request

Here's a thought for an SO feature.  If an answer has been accepted by OP, but the community overwhelmingly supports a different answer by upvoting it, should a consensus of some number of high rep users be able to change the accepted answer?  It is odd that the person asking the question in the first place, who is often confused and not as knowledgeable as those answering the questions, will ultimately decide which response best addresses the issues he/she has raised.  Usually it works out fine, but I have seen a number of questions where the best answer is not actually the selected answer.

Comment: In that event, you should also suggest editing the question to adapt to the proposed accepted answer.

Comment: @devnull: Adapting a question to an answer is the wrong way around.

Comment: @juergend Did I express approval on the original proposal.  Does a statement need to be tagged _sarcasm_?

Comment: See also [Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253752/456814).

Answer (score 19):

This has been proposed many times before (on the old Meta site):

> [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

and has been rejected every single time.

The accept check mark indicates the answer that the person asking the question feels **helped them the most**. There's no requirement for it to be the best answer - that's what votes are for. There have been requests for down-voted accepted answers not to be displayed first:

> [Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot)

and

> [Let's move some negatively scored answers from the top spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot)

But these have also been declined.

This is unlikely to change.

Comment: It is a bit backward, however.  We have always said that the best SO questions are those that benefit *future* readers the most.  In fact we still to this day close questions that are "too localized" if they cannot possibly have value to anyone but the OP proximate to when they asked the question.  If a community of experts decide that one answer has the best chance of being helpful to future readers, shouldn't that one get the checkmark?

Comment: @JohnDibling - The default sorting is by votes. So in these cases straight under the answer the OP deemed most helpful is the answer the community deems to be best.

Comment: @JohnDibling remember there's that shiny gold populist badge for someone who writes an answer that 2x outscores the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelT:  I don't really care about the badges.

Comment: @JohnDibling I've got an answer that outscores the accepted by 3x.  ChrisF had one (that until recently) outscored the accepted by 150 points (partly because the accepted was at -65) that wasn't corrected until a year and a half later. Accept is about what helped the person who asked the question - the votes are from the community. Two different things.

Comment: @MichaelT:  I get that.  But there is a disconnect when the site's criteria for good questions is "is it valuable to a global audience" but the the site's apparent criteria for good answers is "is it valuable to this one specific person?"

Comment: I'm becoming more and more sympathetic to the idea of unlocking the accepted answer from being the first one presented in the sort order by default. People keep flagging us to remove the accepted mark from outright wrong answers that are accepted and sorted about correct ones, and many people I've talked to outside of the site are baffled as to why we sort in this manner. Why does one person have a vote that automatically outweighs everyone else? I may bring this back up on the new Meta as a point of discussion.

Comment: @BradLarson If you do so, could you tag me in a comment so I can upvote and favorite it? I'm pretty sure I'll be in favor.

Comment: @BradLarson late 2015 and this is still the case. :|

Comment: @Qix - *whistles*: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot#comment859351_264047

Comment: @BradLarson mmm my words are so yummy today. 

Comment: The argument that default sorting is by votes no longer applies. By default the "accepted" answer shows first then the top voted.