# Is it ok to ask to upvote/accept my own answers?

Tags: discussion

I am *not* doing that. This is something I saw some people doing.

**Case 1:**

- A relatively high rep (3k+, as I remember) users asks a question.
- Another relatively high rep user X provides an answer.
- The answer is valid, but the OP chooses to accept some other answer of user Y.
- User X asks the OP, "why did you not accept my answer?".
- OP explains why.
- Then X asks OP "ok then, **why don't you upvote my answer** at least". *(emphasis mine)*

Now this happened a while ago, and I do not remember where. But I ignored this because the voter (OP) is high rep and knows the way around in SO, and knows that he can abstain despite user X's requests.

But today this happened.

**Case 2:**

- A very low rep user (<10 rep) asks a question.
- A relatively high rep user (7k+) Provides an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955743/1461424).
- And then this high rep user says "Hope it works for you. If it works, **please upvote and mark as accepted**" *(emphasis mine)*

So my questions:

- Is this behavior acceptable?
- If not, what action should we take?

Comment: It's gauche to be sure, but it doesn't look like a hanging offense to me. I'd recommend just ignoring it and moving on.

Comment: BTW, comments containing the word "accept" are removed with a single flag.

Comment: Related - [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie in SO)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in)

Comment: This sounds like a special case of an experienced user teaching a new user SO etiquette. 

Questions on SO need answers to be 'accepted' unlike most other forum formats, which might not be immediately clear to a new user.

Comment: @Obversity: Well in that case, would not it be better to say "you _can_ accept an answer of your liking" rather than saying "please accept mine".

Comment: @Krumia Strictly speaking he did **not** just say "please accept mine". He said (or meant to say) "***IF*** this answer worked for, and you find it correct and satisfying, please upvote and accept it". This is exactly what should happen, and, to me, it just looks as a simple way to let new users know how they should behave when they find something useful. I don't see why specializing the comment to your own answer should be bad. If there are other answers, I'd hope the OP would realize that you can upvote all of them, and accept any one of them, so I doubt the comment would do any harm.

Comment: I often comment something like "Don't forget to upvote/accept any answers that have helped", usually to try to educate new users on etiquette rather than fishing for rep.

Comment: me, me, me, teacher, pick me, ah, ah, ah, me, I know, me, me, pick me!

Comment: Am I the only one that feels the urge to downvote answers when the answerer does this? I don't unless the answer is bad, but gosh that's annoying.

Comment: Note that the OP did not even have [enough rep to upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Asking them to do so is utterly pointless.

Comment: It's apt to garner a downvote from me.

Comment: I used to try to go out of my way to explain the OP's options: He can accept my answer, accept one of the others, write and accept his own answer, or explain in a comment or a question edit why none of the answers are sufficiently acceptable. But when he's written a "thank you! that fixed it!" comment on my answer and there are no other answers, or the only other answer is voted -4, it's hard not to feel like I'm saying "accept my answer" anyway, so a more generic comment like the one @DavidG suggested seems better.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Asking for upvotes

Pure noise, flag as not constructive.

### Asking the OP to accept *your* answer

Probably not constructive except in very specific situations, if done very gently. Example: OP has posted a comment to the answer saying "Thanks! That did it!" or similar but hasn't accepted any answer, even though the 15-minute window is up, and hasn't posted a similar comment to other answers (or no other answers exist). In a case like that, a gentle reminder with a link (see below) can be constructive. Hopefully, of course, the comment becomes obsolete (when the OP accepts an answer).

Barring that sort of semi-accept from the OP, probably not constructive.

### Asking the OP to accept *someone else's* answer

Could be fine if the answer is very clearly correct, it's been there a while, and it seems like the OP doesn't know about accepting answers.

### Asking the OP to accept *an* answer

Suggesting to the OP that they accept an answer is fine if done properly:

1. Don't do it within 15 minutes of the question being posted, they **can't** accept an answer.
2. Do it as a post on the question, not your answer.
3. Do it by saying something like:

   > If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

   *(There's no magic link for that page yet, so [I've asked for one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239710/add-magic-link-to-somebody-answers).)*

If you see those and they're more than a day old, I'd flag 'em as obsolete.

Comment: Please accept this answer, as it's far better than the one you got now.

Comment: @Jongware: my next question on meta: **Is it ok to bug OP to accept some other answer, because I think the other answer is better?** :P

Comment: @Krumia: related to [Overriding Accepted Answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252015/overriding-accepted-answers). You could leave a comment on the accepted answer, with your reasons why the other is better. (Sure is funny to see how my half-serious comment above *was* taken seriously :)).

Comment: Well, the answer _is_ better @Jongware :)

Comment: +1 for magic links; pure voodoo, never knew about them. Thanks!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yep, I've had that happen quite a few times both on answers of mine and of other people's.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: You're right, "probably not constructive" is too harsh, and incomplete. I've fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Maybe a bit philosophical, but if asking to up-vote is "noise" then votes are useless noise as well. If votes have some reason to be here, other than fun or emotion, then there **must** be a situation when asking to up-vote is reasonable and adds to collaboration.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a popup saying *"you can accept (and optionally upvote) the answer rather than saying >>thank you<< in comment"* if the OP who never accepted an answer would post such a comment.

Comment: For suggesting the OP accept an answer, I usually add something along the lines, "If the answers didn't help, could you edit your question with more details?" That way, they will hopefully provide more information so the real answer can be posted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder With all due respect If the user has spent time in answering the question, and lets say the answer is highly worthy to be accepted then why should he not also ask for an upvote to the answer. Its the reputation that pushes most people to help others on SO. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - Search for "asking for upvote" here on meta. You'll find an overwhelming consensus that it's not okay. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I tend to consider and flag those as *not constructive*. If anything, we should direct the OP to [*How does accepting an answer work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667), but **only after checking** if s/he has previous accepted questions. If that's true, a comment requesting an accept is pure noise, the OP knows how to do it.

Asking for upvotes is something that we do when we are below 1k, 2k maybe... Doing that with 5k+ doesn't bode well and it's not our problem if they want to associate themselves with reputation begging. If the comment doesn't contain anything relevant to the subject matter, it's flaggable too.

Finally, yes, it's a bummer when the OP acknowledges our answer helps to solve the question but doesn't upvote. Many times I wished to leave a comment *"y u not upvote?!?!"*, but nope, better not, let's check another question.

Comment: Bear in mind a <15 rep user can't upvote anything. High rep users tend to forget that ;)

Comment: @Lucas: And if I remember, new users get a message on profile page to "consider accepting answers". I got one few months back. I think this happens when a newbie user gets the voting privilege.

Comment: @Krumia you are correct, new users do get that message

Answer (score 4):

> Is this behavior acceptable?

It depends on the context. What isn't obvious here, is *where* they asked to upvote/accept a certain post. If they did it as part of their answer, then that's just noise and should get edited out.

If they did it as a comment, it is just fine in the case where the OP is a new user of the site. Most often, experienced users do this to **educate beginners about how the SO works** and not for to gaining rep. This is good, as it teaches beginner users to accept answers and get a high accept ratio. If they never accept any answers or are unaware of the accept mechanism, they will get themselves in trouble.

Similarly, an OP leaving a "thank you this is a great answer" comment *instead* of up-voting might also need to be educated about how the site works.

(It seems likely that a fair amount of such comments comes from experienced users going through the "first posts" review queue.)

One should of course leave such educational comments in an objective, impartial manner, without promoting your own answer, or starting some debate about why another answer was accepted instead of your own (assuming the other answer is also correct).

But note that such comments are only needed if the OP is an obvious beginner with no accepted answers. Otherwise, the comments are just noise and you could flag them as "not constructive".

Answer (score 0):

Flag the comment as **not constructive**, it will be removed.

Comment: It depends on the case and context. Teaching new users about the system and badgering the OP are different, and while the keyword is blacklisted, they may not always be flag-worthy.