# Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, upvotes, sorting

One doesn't have to look around SO very long before you find questions with accepted answers that are either dated to the point of being deprecated, or which were just flat-out wrong even in their own time.

Often, there will be another, correct answer, and many times this answer has been upvoted beyond the accepted answer. Sometimes in these cases, the accepted answer even has negative votes.

It seems to me that just because an answer is accepted doesn't mean it should be the top answer shown, as it gives the OP (who by now may be disinterested in the question) a lot of influence over the answer order shown relative to the community, but the pervasive philosophy of SO is that in the end the community will converge on right answers and sort things out. This problem is exacerbated more if you don't switch your answer ordering to vote-based, (which I didn't even discover until today despite visiting the site for years).

Does it make sense to let the community outweigh the OP when it comes to answer ordering? Does it seem to anyone else to contradict the underlying philosophy of how the site works?

Comment: Are you saying you always take the OP's word for what is the best answer and never look at the other answers? What if you disagree that the highest voted answer is the best? You always at least *skim* the rest, right?

Comment: Related though much weaker: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course I do. I'm just saying the ordering could be better. If I want to order by votes I'd prefer the top voted question be on top, regardless of what the OP thought. For all I know, he accepted the first answer given with no basis.

Comment: @Deduplicator I find it a little ironic that the accepted answer to that question is substantially similar to my idea, and had a ton of upvotes.

Comment: Related: [Why are negative score accepted answers still at the top?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255706/3524344)

Comment: Hm. Actually, I never accepted *any* answer there, as nothing changed, the most-upvoted answer seems far too radical (and a bit of too much venting about issues caused by the current state), and the second one is somewhat missing the point, imho.

Comment: my bad, I guess I assumed it was accepted because it was at the top :P

Comment: This is a major problem for **outdated accepted answers**. For example, super long, convoluted answers for low versions of Java are always on top when there's a one-liner in Java 7. Community votes usually end up supporting the more recent versions of Java, but users still see a 20-line solution from Java 3 on top, and I can imagine that a lot of new/anonymous users don't even bother scrolling down...

Comment: I have [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25029785/3650944) where the top voted answer _didn't_ answer my question. But this is probably an unusual pattern.

Comment: This feature request is *not* a duplicate of the linked one. `ordering != overriding`

Comment: Related to @ChrisCirefice's point, there was [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/2359271) not too long ago.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how this post from a year ago is a duplicate of a post from a few days ago?

Comment: @SteveLadavich: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326291/how-is-my-meta-question-from-a-year-ago-a-duplicate-of-something-asked-two-days

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It might surprise people, but I actually fully support this. I've [had concerns about the asker's vote overriding the community's for a while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252015/overriding-accepted-answers#comment6753_252016), and to non-regulars, this seems bizarre.

The [community feels that accept votes still serve a useful purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose), but that doesn't mean that we can't remove their sorting preference. The accept mark is very visible, even if the accepted answer is sorted below others, so it's clear what answer the asker chose. I don't think it needs to be pinned to the top.

At best, I think an accept vote should act as a tiebreaker for sorting two equally-voted posts. I see no reason to give the asker a vote that almost completely overrides the community. The asker can be wrong about what is the best solution for a particular problem, and bad or harmful answers can then be sorted above much better ones.

For those arguing that someone could just scroll down the page a bit more, isn't the whole point of this site to provide the best solutions to problems right up front? Why sort at all if you want people to read all answers before proceeding?

I say this as someone who has had to field a *lot* of flags from confused users about why downvoted wrong answers are being sorted ahead of better ones just by virtue of them being accepted by the asker. I feel bad declining these, because I know exactly how bizarre this looks.

I do believe that accept votes should not lock posts to the top of the sort order, and that they should only count as an additional vote on the post they're given to.

Comment: I agree with your answer in totality, including the tie-breaker.

Comment: I could see them counting as a bit more than a single upvote, but otherwise this seems reasonable.

Comment: +1 to @NathanTuggy.  I'd weigh accepted as +10 upvotes.  The community has to clearly win before it overtakes the accepted answer.

Comment: I also like the idea of a hidden weight for the checkmark while at the same time sorting by votes.

Comment: Yet another approach would be to **move the green check mark onto the question**, say, just below the "favorite" star, and make it an anchor to the accepted answer with a tooltip like "the author of this question has accepted an answer as the most helpful" instead of having it alter the sort order.

Comment: @AirThomas: as an 'also' that would be OK; as an 'instead', I think it less desirable.  The accepted answer should still be marked as such, even if it no longer places first in the list of answers.

Comment: @yzorg Why give such a high weight to acceptance? After all, the OP is unlikely to be an expert on the topic, or they would not have needed to ask the question. Many questions don't get 10 votes total.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think it preserves the original (current) reason accepted answers are at the top: as a reward to the OP.  As a reader I don't mind having to scroll for a slightly better answer, or when the question hasn't had many eyes on it.  I do mind reading through a very bad accepted answer when a much better answer is available.  Again, I think the community should have to clearly win to overtake the accepted answer.  (Take with grain of salt as I'm a long time SE user, maybe I just don't want my cheese to be moved.)

Comment: @yzorg The influence of any constant weighting on the accepted answer will tend to vary with time/views on the question. +10? +100? Tough to predict what the outcome will be. I don't see any advantage over the simple "tie-breaker" approach.

Comment: @AirThomas Just my opinion from my years as an SO user.  This bugs me the most when the accepted answer is more than 10 votes below the highest community answer.  I'd be fine with a ratio.  But I think +10 is a clear rule that's easy to remember and easy to eyeball.

Comment: There should still be some sort of option to readily see the accepted answer. Whether that's a sort option or a jump to link or whatever, if the question has several answers, the accepted one should be readily accessible.

Comment: Maybe not 10 votes, but 5 or 6, plus tie-breaking if two still end up being equal

Comment: How about giving the user the option to ignore answer marks when ordering by votes? I want to see the answer with the most votes at the top - but I accept that others might not. So give _me_ the choice.

Comment: This would really improve the experience of using SO. When the accepted answer is really long, it might not be obvious that there are other ones below it that answer the question better.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the meta, but this answer was voted +83/-2 as of 2016/02, 13 months after it was posted. So why hasn't this feature been implemented yet? it isn't even controversionally discussed around here

Comment: @Blauhirn I believe it's been implemented now. Example: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the/36878631#36878631).

Comment: @bcsb1001 Interesting! but what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788887/object-binding-to-listbox-does-not-work/23789228#23789228 ? I've seen another one recently, too

Comment: @bcsb1001 no, it hasn't been implemented yet. That example is because the accepted answer is from the same person who made the question, so it isn't pinned in the top.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly happen that OP clearly accepted a wrong answer mainly because there was a mistake in some part that OP fixed eventually without even noticing (typo, incorrect terms, ...). But generally, the accepted answer is the one that was used by OP. So at least he found it the most useful for his particular problem.

On the other end votes represent the opinion of the community on the quality of the answer, but they do not come necessarily from people having the problem. So it is not surprising that accepted and highest vote are 2 different answers.

It is clear that non accepted answers must be sorted according to the votes. But if the accepted one is not sticked at first place, it could easily go very down in the page. Worse, a user looking too rapidly could think that no answer was actually accepted, sothat there were good answers (upvoted) but none directly solving the problem.

That's the reason why I think that the current policy of having accepted answer on top is better, at least you immediately see if there is an accepted one !

Anyway, I used SO as a reference quite a long time before posting there. And I never stopped at first answer at least for complex questions having different answers. Because sometimes, I used a medium voted answer was more adapted to **my** problem. But I always was more confident as soon as I saw that OP accepted one answer (even it was not what I used) because I was sure the problem was solved.

But of course I'm not a moderator and I'm not concerned by dealing with flags ...

Comment: I think especially for c++, which has changed dramatically from 2008, a lot of answers that were canonical are now deprecated or actively discouraged. From what I've seen, OPs from 2+ years ago have little interest in doing maintenance, and the current ordering system hampers the community from doing it for them.

Comment: A reader should care of the date of questions and answers. And the highest voted answer is at least in second position, whereas with the other ordering the accepted answer could be much further.

Comment: It's just a matter of taste... you say it's a simple solution, just scroll, and I don't disagree. But I think that in the vast majority of cases, the most upvoted answer is better than the accepted one (when they aren't the same), and I say why should I have to scroll. It's a question of which UI design is friendlier. I don't think anyone on SO is not skimming through answers, that's not really at issue.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus *It's just a matter of taste*. I do agree ! That's mainly the reason why I was posting a different advice

Comment: I say "amen" to this.  As someone looking for answers to a problem, I am going to look for questions reflecting the same problem and an answer that worked for the person posting that question.  Then I want to see what other answers to that question garnered the most votes.  So, the current order (upvoted first, all other sorted by upvotes) works just fine for the guy looking for answers... and isn't that the goal?

Answer (score -2):

What if an accepted answer could become 2nd in position. Could it become 3rd or more?

The OP to have a veto on top answer doesn't feel right,  but the veto takes the best answer as voted by the community not further than second place. AND the veto helps engage question askers. Empowering question askers contributes to SO as a place to be.

For me SO being a place where you want to ask questions outweighs the right for the community to place there answer higher than the accepted.The veto on top position for the OP is beneficial to us all.

I'll always check the second answer. Though I have to admit to have tried some of the less valuable accepted answer first in the past.

Comment: While I am all for what is being discussed in the comments of Brad's answer, I think you have an interesting point here. What would the OPs think if the answer they selected, they chose as the correct answer for their question, suddenly dropped below three answers they felt weren't adequate or did not satisfy the question? It's definitely worth considering how the OPs would take this.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not made for the OP, it's made for all the other users that find the question later. I doubt that many askers even revisit their question later.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch It's well-documented all over meta that in fact they typically do not.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch without the OP there is not much to find for others, is there? And my point isn't that without OP's veto on top answer he wouldn't ask his question. It's about him motivating to ask and come back to accept.