# Why are accepted answers more prominent than answers with more votes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes, sorting

I think there's a very good chance this question has already been asked, but I've not found it. If it has, I will delete this with apologies.

Why are accepted answers more prominent than answers with more votes? I guess the point of this question is  to suggest that maybe it ought not be so. When I'm doing my own research, I sometimes do not notice that the top answer is not the best answer as judged by the community, at least not right away.

Whereas a person who asks a question does not even have exclusive ownership of the content of their question, I wonder if it isn't inconsistent that they have exclusive control over which answer appears first and most prominently.

If you don't like the idea of displaying the answer with the most votes first, even above the accepted answer, then what about giving the highest voted answer more prominence in some other way?

Comment: See also [Do accepted answers still serve a useful purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose) which contests the idea of publicly displaying the acceptance status as a whole.

Comment: @BoltClock see [Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer) right here, at MSO

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for that. I'm more familiar with Brad's original discussion on MSE, which precedes most of these discussions. Would you consider that MSO question a duplicate target for this one?

Comment: @BoltClock upon more carefully re-reading this question, it indeed sounds like a duplicate (I missed that on a first read)

Comment: Is there any reason not to delete this question? Frankly, I don't think anything would be lost if the current "answers" went away.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because the user who asked the question got what s/he wanted and therefore it is important to **let others know that the user is already satisfied**.

Therefore any answer that is welcomed after that, will be for the benefit of others, add more improvements and also just to create a forum for others who have same issue, but may have a different view.

Therefore it should be. The accepted answer to come first, then followed by others, by default others ordered with ones with highest votes. To add value or criticize the accepted answer.

Comment: SE is **not a forum** :/