# Answer with highest vote score is shown only at 5th position

Tags: support, sorting

This question:

[How to make a simple hyperlink in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531621/how-to-make-a-simple-hyperlink-in-xaml)

The answer with the highest vote is listed at 5th position only, and not on top. Why? Many comments say that it is the best answer.

Comment: You have to sort the answers by "vote", not by "activity"

Comment: Does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I loaded the page, I saw it was the second answer, because it was not the accepted one.

I think I know what happened, though.

Currently, it is listed 5th when you click on the "Active" tab, which does not sort by votes.

Note: after clicking `active` then leaving the page, I realized that every other page I looked at was also sorted by `active`. I understand why you got confused (I was confused too for a second).

Comment: Aaaaah yes !!! Saw that the first time! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The way that answers are sorted depends on a few factors:

- **Whether or not the answer is accepted** and is not the OP's answer
- Your immediate sorting preferences

  - The number of votes on a given answer
  - The age of the given answer
  - When the answer was last edited

In this scenario, since the answer with 24 votes is *accepted*, and does not belong to the OP, it is going to show up at the very top of the answer list.

[It'd be nice if it were ordered that way in the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283456/1079354), but presently that's how it is.  Just bear those rules above in mind and you'll be able to suss out what's going on.

Oh, and as a side note:  it's good that you're looking at the other answers.  The accepted answer has more significance to the OP than it should us, but in situations like this, it's always a good idea to look to see if there's something better or more detailed as provided by another answerer.