# How is my meta question from a year ago a duplicate of something asked two days ago?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

So maybe I just don't understand how duplicates work. I had [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer?noredirect=1#comment358139_283456) which I asked a year ago. It was recently marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top), which was asked 2 days ago.

I'm not totally convinced that they are actually duplicates, especially since the new questions uses the support implied from votes on my question as part of its premise (which seems like some weird circular logic if my question is a dupe), but more importantly, how can a question be a duplicate of something that didn't even exist at the time of asking?

Comment: @AniMenon Lets make that question a duplicate of this one:D It already a duplicate of 2 other question... Lets make it 3!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For meta questions, the same [reasoning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651) holds as for questions on the main site:

> If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.

FWIW, I agree that the banner text explaining the closure

> This question has been asked **before**

(emphasis mine) is misleading.

Comment: gotcha. Not sure the new question is better though, and it has basically the same answer, written by the same person.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus agreed - I had already voted to close the *new* question as a duplicate, but it has been reopened again.

Comment: It should probably say "elsewhere" but not sure if that's worth a feature request.

Comment: *'This question has been asked **before**'* Sounds like a new meta question (unless it is a duplicate).

Comment: The new question is more detailed in answers, comments and the question itself. It had more visibility in 2 days than the old question had in over a year. That is why the old question is closed as a dupe of the new one. (And why it shouldn't be re-opened)