# Don't allow Question X to be closed as duplicate of Y when Y is already closed as duplicate of X

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

So this just happened with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) question on meta. It is closed as a duplicate of a question that is closed as a duplicate of it. That means that a user looking at this will always see the "Your answer is somewhere else" banner. Thats nonsensical and if that happens on the main site it will only lead to enormous confusion for users looking.

**Concrete Proposal:** A question cannot be voted to close as a duplicate of a question that currently is closed as a duplicate to the first question.

**Problem Situation:** A user looking to find his answer to a question will always be told "This question already has a answer somewhere else", which means they'll be stuck in a loop of the system telling them to look elsewhere, which is immensely confusing.

**Predicted positive Impact:** The above mentioned infinite loop of duplicate will no longer be possible.

Edit 1:

According to Johannes Kuhn's Answer, its already prevented to close the Q as duplicate when the other one is already a duplicate of it. This happened because it picks the majority close reason and the other already had 4 votes as duplicate. So this is a bug instead. A question should not be marked as a duplicate in these circumstances, but rather closed with the second-most popular close vote reason, or the duplicate votes should automatically be dropped when the other question is closed.

*Here is an image since one question was reopened:*

[image]

Comment: What if both X and Y get their first "Close as dupe" votes before the other one is closed? What if X is Mjölnir'd, when Y has 4 "close as dupe"-votes?

Comment: I'm sure I have tried this once, and already *got* a message like 'This question can't be closed because a loop would occur' (don't remember the exact wording, though).

Comment: @Glorfindel: Maybe that's only the case on main, then?

Comment: I think this should be a SE-wide rule, and that under no circumstances should such a loop occur. That being a thing is counter to what a duplicate banner is supposed to do, which is to guide people to the right answer.

Comment: Would this also happen on Stack Overflow? Can someone post an answer below with links to two duplicate questions (but not currently marked as duplicates)? Close Y as a dupe of X and give X four dupe votes of Y. Then add a fifth close vote of "too broad" on X.

Comment: @Suragch Yes, but how often does that happen? For non-meta sites, an answer is required for the target question, which usually rules out the new question. People don't go to some old question and say "hey, let's look if a newer version of it was posted". But people will say: "Wait, this question has been already asked. Close as duplicate".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Duplicate close votes are based on the best question / best answer, not on their age. Those are subjective, and people might disagree - their might be circular votes indeed. People *do* go around and vote to close old questions, particularly when they stumble upon them in the process of searching for the best duplicate target for a recent question.

Comment: Yes, it may __look__ iike a problem but it really isn't: Both questions already have accepted answers. Looking at their state as closed as dupes  and moving away __without__ looking at the answers is plain dumb and doesn't warrant extra precautions..

Comment: Hold on... So... What your saying is... The post was closed as a duplicate, and the post of which it is a duplicate is a duplicate of the original duplicate..? http://tinyurl.com/q5jnrsy... SO has once again blown my mind...

Comment: @TaW, except that there is nowhere to add a new answer when both are closed as duplicates of each other.

Comment: @Sur: Whoops, you're right! That is a real problem indeed.

Comment: Is it still possible to have a duplicate loop that has more than 2 cycles? I'm asking because I don't think that should be allowed either.

Comment: Related feature request posted (disclosure: by me) three years ago on Meta.SE: [Remove votes to close question X as a duplicate of Y if question Y is closed as a duplicate of X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163408/remove-votes-to-close-question-x-as-a-duplicate-of-y-if-question-y-is-closed-as)

Comment: Why is this a problem in the first place? Often the duplicate chain has a variety of answers that are worthwhile seeing different approaches to same problem. One of my highest voted answers happens to be on a question marked as duplicate yet it gets lots of traffic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To [Johannes Kuhn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326348/dont-allow-question-x-to-be-closed-as-duplicate-of-y-when-y-is-already-closed-a/326349#326349): good find, trouble maker :)

Next build will implement [Servy's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326348/dont-allow-question-x-to-be-closed-as-duplicate-of-y-when-y-is-already-closed-a#comment358673_326349):

> @Deduplicator You could automatically resolve it by immediately clearing all close as duplicate flags when the target question is closed as a duplicate of the current question (leaving all other types of close votes, as well as duplicates for other targets). Would prevent these cycles.

When a question is closed as a duplicate, its originals are examined for dupe votes pointing at the now-closed duplicate - these votes are then invalidated.

Comment: Now we need another *trouble maker* to test the new setup ;)

Comment: I added a unit test, what more do you want?! ;)

Comment: Can those close voters vote again, right?

Comment: @Braiam not currently.  If there's reason to close vote again, it indicates (to me) that something more is wrong and the question should be flagged for mod attention.

Comment: What if the duplicate got reopened? Can we continue to vote to close the other one now? Sometimes someone votes to close the wrong one, and now suddenly all other close votes are gone?

Comment: Great! Now we can't have 2-cycles. What about n-cycles, with n>2 ?

Comment: Jarod, you may consider tagging status-completed [this cross-site duplicate at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163408/165773): "Remove votes to close question X as a duplicate of Y if question Y is closed as a duplicate of X"

Comment: @Oriol: Those are presumably still possible. They're quite rare, though; SO doesn't currently [seem to](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507509/tasty-and-delicious-dupe-loops) have any dupe loops of length between 3 and 20 (and I'd be very surprised if there were any loops with *more* than 20 questions in them).

Answer (score 52):

As someone who cast the final close vote, here is what happened:

- [Question 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top?noredirect=1) and [Question 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer?noredirect=1) both got some close votes as duplicate of each other.
- [Question 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer?noredirect=1) was closed as duplicate of [Question 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top?noredirect=1)
- [Question 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top?noredirect=1) had 4 close votes as duplicate of [Question 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer?noredirect=1)

Now I could not resist and cast a close vote as "too broad" (yeah, bad idea, sorry, couldn't resist)

- Because [Question 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top?noredirect=1) already had 4 close votes as duplicate, the duplicate reason "won" - creating a circle.
- I wasn't able to cast a close vote as duplicate of the other question, I got an error stating that this would create a circle.

**tl;dr**: That was a rare race-condition. May happen on meta.

Comment: so according to that, this makes that a bug, not a feature

Comment: _Now I could not resist and cast a close vote as "too broad"_. As I'm sure you're well aware, existing votes shouldn't influence your judgement of the question / answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm aware. Wanted to see the circle.

Comment: Hm... I don't see any good way to automatically resolve that situation, so would call for an auto-flag to bring in some moderator.

Comment: @Deduplicator You could automatically resolve it by immediately clearing all close as duplicate flags when the target question is closed as a duplicate of the current question (leaving all other types of close votes, as well as duplicates for other targets).  Would prevent these cycles.

Comment: Another reason to return to listing the separate reasons for which a question was closed rather than letting the "winner" take all.

Comment: It may make sense to use the posting time of the questions and perhaps the vote count of the questions as some sort of rule structure for not allowing a dupe vote. Something like: "if Q1 was posted before Q2 and Q1 has positive votes, then Q1 cannot  be closed as a dupicate of Q2."

Comment: @[c358528](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326348/dont-allow-question-x-to-be-closed-as-duplicate-of-y-when-y-is-already-closed-a?cb=1#comment358528_326349) - as a QA engineer, can't agree more. An opportunity to reproduce such a rare and unique bug is worth too much to be squandered!

Comment: @Lmo no, closing duplicates into the future is a valid action.

Comment: @Yakk is that due to quality of the older question (Q1)?

Comment: @Lmo If the newer question is a better canonical question (and answer!), close the older as dupe of the newer.

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth taking this one step further. Rather than trying only to avoid simple loops, it may be worth eliminating dupe chains altogether. So rather than having situations [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2800):

```
A is a dupe of B
B is a dupe of C
```

we detect that (maybe at dupe closing time) and change it such that:

```
A is a dupe of C
B is a dupe of C
```

This way we wind up with a clear canonical question that doesn't take n>1 extra clicks to get to.

---

It may also be worth adding a header on the canonical question that states "Hey, there are some duplicates to this question, click here to check them out if the answers here were insufficient, but make sure to return here if you have a new answer." That message may need some refinement if actually implemented. Clicking on "here" could open a fold with links to the duplicates, or open a page listing them all, possibly with a short snippet.

---

Another possibility is adding some method of changing which of the duplicates is the canonical one, in case a later question has already received a fantastic answer before being closed as a dupe, but the existing canonical question only has lesser quality answers. This could possibly be presented as votes on the dupe fold/page, but I'm not sure if that would be too noisy or confusing. Another idea in need of refinement.

Comment: 1. There might be, and often is, value in pointing to the intermediate dupe instead of directly to the master, as the intermediate might be easier applied to the original question. Also, dupe-closing the intermediate might have been wrong, and will be shortly corrected... 2. Regarding the dupes linking to the master: Those are all in the "linked"-list, though intermixed with other links. 3. Changing which is the master is simple, especially for gold-badge-holders: Reopen and close the other way around. Anything more complicated is probably too complicated and confusing.

Comment: @Deduplicator The clear list of other duplicates in the header should make it easy to find those others. Currently, if there's multiple branches leading to the same master, as in `A=>B=>C` and `X=>Y=>C`, the X and Y can't easily get to A or B nor vice versa.

Comment: We already have the list of other duplicates in the related questions panel.

Comment: @IanRingrose The related questions panel lists questions that the site's algorithms *thinks* are related, they may or may not be duplicates and being a duplicate does not force it to appear there. The linked questions panel does include duplicates, seemingly in both directions, but does not distinguish between duplicates, tangents, or questions that someone thought was a duplicate, but turned out not to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the best solution would be to require the appropriate number of close votes for a single reason for closure.  This would also prevent the situation I've run into, where I voted to close a question as a duplicate after finding the appropriate canonical question, and saw the question closed as "too broad" - which in my opinion, it clearly was not - without the resulting link to the canonical question.

Votes to close would then be allowed to specify multiple acceptable reasons for egregious questions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

When question A is closed as a duplicate of question B, we need to examine question B.

All "close as duplicates of" votes on question B should be cleared, not just the ones that close it as duplicates of question A.  This is because the alternative is potentially expensive and error-prone:

Alternatively, examine all of the duplicates votes on B.  For each such duplicate, examine the question that it is claiming B is a duplicate of.  If it is A, remove the duplicate vote on B.  If it is not A *but is a duplicate of another question*, recursively walk the duplicate chain until you return to a question you have already seen, or you reach A, or reach the end of the chain.  If you reach A, remove the original duplicate vote on B.

This second algorithm is tricky and more expensive.  So I'd just strip all duplicate votes on anything that something is closed as duplicate of (not duplicate *status*, just pending votes) and call it a day or some other compromise that errs on the side of clearing duplicate votes.