# Please remove status-declined from "Please unpin the accepted answer from the top" or post an official answer

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I read this:

[Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top)

which has great community support but Jan 19 at 3:20 2017 it was [status-declined by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/326095/8)

so I start to search for the reason why, reading question and answers also on these:

[Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer)

[Let's move some negatively scored answers from the top spot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot)

[Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever/)

The closes I get to some official explain is in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268806/320339) by [bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet):

> I've yet to come up with solution that has been accepted internally

however it ends

> I won't [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) this because I'm still working on some possible ideas, but this is most likely a long shot.

also [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) left a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top#comment434566_326095)

> Chances of coming to a workable consensus on this in... At least the next year... Are slim

According to me if you are still *"working on consensus"* remove the tag and when you have "consensus" post an answer adding again the relative tag.

or am I misunderstanding the status-declined tag?, it's used if no solution in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: Just tag it [tag:status-6-to-8-weeks] ...

Comment: [meta-tag:status-6-to-8-weeks] @rene

Comment: So...you want to unpin Brad's accepted answer from the top? Seriously, the description of [[meta-tag:status-declined]] is "indicates that the feature request or bug will not be implemented or fixed at the present time", so I'd say that's appropriate. They don't seem to have any concrete plan to implement it.

Comment: @cody I'm missing reasoning behind no plan, where does it say they have no plan? I read all as "we are still searching consensus"

Comment: A plan is something that you need to have, otherwise it doesn't exist. They aren't planning to do anything. I don't really know how better to explain this. At *best*, they're thinking about it, but since they've been thinking about it for *years* and still haven't come up with a plan, I'm pretty sure that means it isn't going to get implemented any time soon. Tagging it [[tag:status-planned]] would be *very* misleading.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not suggesting that tag, I'm suggesting no tag, too me it's confusing to tag status-declined, since I saw it as always indicate official response that on important meta has an official answer. To indicate we are searching consensus either you put no tag or invent a new one like rene suggested [status-we-need-to-make-up-or-minds-after-6-8]. but hey maybe it's me missing the point of status-declined, maybe it's more "don't bug us with this now, we are developing topbar"

Comment: @CodyGray there's also the [meta-tag:status-review] available.  Although based on years of review, that's potentially mislead too.

Comment: Just settle on my suggestion and call it day. The world will not change nor end due to a or no tag ...

Comment: day (12 more to go)

Comment: If they haven't reached a consensus, isn't the answer still 'No'? They haven't actually un-declined the request at this point.

Comment: @BSMP aah ok the FR start with status-declined and then are moved to status-review. :P

Comment: *too be more serious, I just don't like how an FR like that with massive support is made status-declined without no reasoning or answer, other then at this moment we can't reach consensus, but true rene is sadly correct lets call it day and watch some football (European style)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back with fresh eyes and less of a splitting headache, I think perhaps I've hit upon a better way of explaining this than I could come up with yesterday.

Basically, although they've considered it multiple times, the team still hasn't been able to decide on what to do. As such, the feature is not being planned, much less is it approved and scheduled for implementation.

Because the team can't decide what to do, they aren't doing anything. Yes, like you said, features start out "declined" by default. They can be moved up to "review", and then either demoted back to "declined" or promoted up to "approved" (and eventually "completed"), but [every proposed feature starts out with a -100 point score](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).

As I did manage to come up with yesterday, tagging it [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) would be very misleading, because there's no tangible plan.

Tagging it [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) probably would have been appropriate at some point, when the community managers indicated that it was actively being discussed and reviewed, but at this point, after they've talked about it and *still* have been unable to agree on what to do or come up with a concrete plan, I think it would be equally misleading to have it tagged as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). As far as I can tell, as an outsider looking in, it is no longer being *actively* reviewed. And if we don't keep the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag reserved for things that are being *actively* reviewed, it loses all meaning. *Everything* presented here is reviewed at some level, and even features that have been declined are subject to rising from the ashes like the mythical Phoenix, quite like the litany of "make the top bar sticky" feature requests from 2009–11 that were repeatedly declined, yet suddenly…

It seems that your real complaint is this:

> I just don't like how an FR like that with massive support is made [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) without no reasoning or answer, other then at this moment we can't reach consensus

and that is a completely fair point. It would be nice if someone from the team could post an answer there, even if just to explain that they talked about it until they were blue in the feet, but were ultimately unable to shog everyone into agreement.

Still, all things considered, I think leaving the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag is appropriate. Consider the alternative, which would be to simply remove the [status-*] tag. To someone unfamiliar with the history surrounding the issue, reading the apparently strong community support (with endorsement even coming from a moderator), I think that would definitely send the wrong signal. It's *not* coming down the pike any time soon, and for all intents and purposes, you might as well consider it to be declined. If it rises from the grave again, to be implemented at some later date, then that's lovely, but we can simply change the tag at that time.

In other words, **[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) is the most accurate tag we currently have to represent the state of that proposal**, so it's the one that should stay. We don't have a [status-6-to-8-weeks](/questions/tagged/status-6-to-8-weeks) or [status-we-tried-but-well-we-still-dunno](/questions/tagged/status-we-tried-but-well-we-still-dunno) or [status-ugh-running-a-huge-community-website-is-so-hard](/questions/tagged/status-ugh-running-a-huge-community-website-is-so-hard) tag, and while one of those might be, strictly speaking, more accurate, they wouldn't really convey any more useful message.

Comment: So, does that mean that this discussion is [status-declined]? ;-)

Comment: Thanks Cody, yes I probably had the wrong idea of status-declined, I saw it as a decision we decline this, not as tag that also represent "we don't know what to do yet and we will not know soon, lets close this for now". However, to me the status-declined tag was very confusing, I did spend significant time to search for answer only find discussion telling, "yes, we should do something, but it's hard to get consensus", which to me did not merit the declined tag.

Comment: *the only strange conclusion is that most of community old FR, new ask question interface, reduce cv, merge NAA, VLQ ecc, should all be marked with status-declined?*